# How to write a remark/text under a groupplot-windows

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, legend, groupplots

The legend of my last groupplot is printed below the last groupplot so far so good. But how can I write a text above the groupplot like a headline? Normally, I would just at an legendentry without legendimage but unfortunately this will increase the space between the first and second column. Therefore I tried to set a node on the axis and then write a command but that doesn't work as expect either. Has someone an idea, how to solve the problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=1.12
}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
height = 5cm,
 width = 10cm,
group style={
    group name=my plots,
    group size=1 by 2,%10
    },
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={cells={align=left}},
    legend style={draw=none},
    legend style={at={(3cm,-2cm)},anchor=north,align=left,draw=white,
    legend columns=4, 
    legend style={
    /tikz/every even column /.append style={column sep=1.5cm}
        },
    },
    legend style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}}, 
    ]
\nextgroupplot[ylabel={rnd}]
  \addplot {rnd*6};

\nextgroupplot[ylabel={rnd}]

%1 -- spacing betwen columns breaks
% \addlegendimage{empty legend}
%\addlegendentry{\hspace{-.63cm} Some explanations to sth \dots}
%\addlegendimage{empty legend}\addlegendentry{ }
%\addlegendimage{empty legend}\addlegendentry{ }
%\addlegendimage{empty legend}\addlegendentry{ }

 %2 doesn't work
%\node[below right=1cm] (T) {Hello text};

\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:-6,-6);
\node[below  = 0.31cm] at (A) {Some explanations to sth \dots};


 \addplot {rnd*2};
\addlegendentry{test 20134214};
 \addplot {rnd*-.05};
\addlegendentry{test 2012};

 \addplot {rnd*3-8};
\addlegendentry{test 201};

 \addplot {rnd*6};


\addlegendentry{tes};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: 1. ´\addlegendimage{empty legend}´]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about what you actually want to do. To add a description above the groupplots, the simplest thing would be to use `title=..` in the options of the first `\nextgroupplot`.

If you want to place a description above the legend, you can give it a name (`name=..` in the `legend style`), and place a node relative to this. You only need *one* `legend style`, by the way.

Another route would be to place a node relative to the last axis. You have `name=my plots` in the `group style`, so the name of the bottom axis is `my plots c1r2` (column 1, row 2). Hence, you could say e.g.

```
\node [below] at (my plots c1r2.south) {The road goes ever on and on};
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} %pgfplots loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{
compat=1.12
}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,positioning}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  samples=3,
  height = 5cm,
  width = 10cm,
  group style={
    group name=my plots,
    group size=1 by 2,%10
  },
  legend cell align=left,
  legend style={
   name=mylegend,
   cells={align=left},
   draw=none,
   at={(3cm,-2cm)},anchor=north,align=left,
  },
  legend columns=4 
  ]
\nextgroupplot[ylabel={rnd},title=This is awesome!]
  \addplot {rnd*6};

\nextgroupplot[ylabel={rnd}]


 \addplot {rnd*2};
\addlegendentry{test 20134214};
 \addplot {rnd*-.05};
\addlegendentry{test 2012};

 \addplot {rnd*3-8};
\addlegendentry{test 201};

 \addplot {rnd*6};

\addlegendentry{tes};
\end{groupplot}
\node[above=0cm of mylegend] {Some explanations to sth \dots};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```